# Does BlackBerry enterprise server support COM?

Tags: c++, blackberry

Do BlackBerry enterprise server APIs expose any COM interface to write applications in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The Blackberry Administration API is invoked via SOAP. You can use a C++ SOAP proxy generator to interface with the BAAPI from C++.

Comment: Thanks for response, one last thing i need, BAAPI is only through webservices? or can we have normal APIs to access BES database? 
p.s. i gave a upvote :)